# What is better to use for generating HTML from java, but not on web related project

Tags: java, templates, xslt, freemarker

What HTML template is better to use in project that is not a web related, in we particular need to generate html from xml and java objects?
Is Freemarker a good template engine? Or maybe is better just to use xslt transformation?

Comment: I would use Velocity.  You can start with a HTML document and template it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use a host of technologies before XSLT, including things like FreeMarker, Velocity, [Mustache](https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java), [MVEL](http://mvel.codehaus.org/MVEL+2.0+Templating+Guide), Groovy, etc. I prefer FreeMarker over Velocity due to FM's better error handling.

A lot of it depends on how smart you want your templates to be: Mustache forces very dumb templates, Groovy builders allow insanely smart ones.

If you have a lot of XSLT expertise, or have everything exposed as XML, then XSL would be fine--it's misunderstood and isn't as bad as people say it is, but it's verbose, and for generating HTML it sure seems like other options are more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I've used both XSLT and FreeMarker extensively, and would limit my use of either one to its respective strengths:

- Freemarker for generating markup with lots of lists and template based forms using data from objects which you can modify directly or indirectly
- XSLT for generating markup with lots of semantic classes and IDs but limited forms and lists

**References**

- [Transforming XML Data with XSLT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/transformingXML.html)
- [Alfresco Wiki: Template Guide](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Template_Guide)